# how to validate custom fields using variables in magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml, validation, variables

[image]

> here have two fields
>
> 1)Fields_1
>
> 2)Fileds_2

here  **i want to validate Field_2  < Filed_1**  (less than )

how i do this in magenot 2???

Field_2 Tag

```
  <div class="field">
                            <label class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Current quote amount') ?>:</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text"
                                       class='input-text'
                                       readonly='readonly'
                                       value="<?php  $sellerlowestquoteDetails=$quoteHelper->getSellerLowestQuote($quote->getId());
                                       $seller_detail='';
                                       //echo count($sellerlowestquoteDetails);

                                       if(count($sellerlowestquoteDetails)>0){
                                           foreach($sellerlowestquoteDetails as $sellerlowestquoteDetail){
                                               $seller_detail=$sellerlowestquoteDetail;
                                           }
                                       }
                                       if(count($sellerlowestquoteDetails)>0) {
                                           echo $seller_detail['seller_quote_price'];
                                       }
                                       else{
                                           echo "N/A";
                                       }

                                       //print_r($seller_detail['seller_quote_price']);/* @escapeNotVerified */ //$tt=$quoteHelper->getSellerLowestQuote($quote->getId());


                                       ?>"
                                       name='customer_iiid'
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
 <div class="field">
                                <?php $price = number_format($sellerquote->getSellerQuotePrice(), 2);?>
                                <label class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Your Quote Price')." (".$currencySymbol.")" ?>:</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text"
                                        class='input-text required-entry validate-number validate-greater-than-zero'
                                         <?php echo ($priceDisabled1)?"readonly='readonly'":''?>
                                        value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $price ?>"
                                        name='seller_quote_price'
                                    />
                                    <small>Give your quote price.</small>
                                    <input type="hidden"
                                         readonly='readonly'
                                        value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $price ?>"
                                        name='quote_price'
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
<div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="back-link">
                <a href="javascript:;"
                    onclick="javascript: window.history.back();"
                    class="left"
                >&laquo; <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Back') ?></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php if (!$disabled) : ?>
        <?php    $block->getsellerupdateCollection($sellerquote->getQuoteId(),$quote->getCustomerId())

        ?>
            <button class="button wk-mp-qs-btn"
                title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Update') ?>"
                type="submit"
                id="save_butn"
            >
                <span><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Update') ?></span></span>
            </button>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('View Quote') ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "<h2 class='wk_new_msg'>".__("To BECOME SELLER PLEASE CONTACT TO ADMIN.")."</h2>";
}?>
<?php
$formData = [
    'quoteForm'     =>  '#form-quote',
    'saveButton'    =>  '#save_butn'
];
$serializedFormData = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($formData);
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "WkMpQuotesystem": <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $serializedFormData; ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where are you making these fields ?

Comment: custom module bro...

Comment: can you share your form code of these fields

Comment: ur asking  full  .phtml  file

Comment: yes share your form code

Comment: @abdus added bro,,,,

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type = "text" id ="price1" ?>
<input type = "text" id ="price2" ?>
<div id = "error"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#price2").keypress(function(){

        var price1 = document.getElementById("price1").value;
        var price2 = document.getElementById("price2").value;
        if(parseInt(price2) > parseInt(price1) ){
        //alert("price 2 is greater then price1");
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML ="price 2 is greater then price1" ;

        }
      })
    });
</script>
```

check if it will solve your problem

Comment: this is  not  working....

Comment: it's validating but when i click on submit  button it's updating ......values